# I thought normal force works only on $y$-direction, how it also works on $x$-direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I am taking physics. There was a problem which was talking to a person who can exert force to the book so that it won't slip down vertically. In the answer book it was saying, the two normal force is working on the $x$-direction. Could anyone clear me up about this normal force?

Comment: Normal is perpendicular to surface as surface here is vertical so perpendicular to it is x axis

Comment: @UniverseA7 That's the answer. The normal force is perpendicular to the surface, although, like any other force, you can break it down into two component forces.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering

Answer (score 4):

Normal force is a contact force , It doesnt matter which direction you are applying the force. It can be thought of as due to some force applied on an object when making contact there is some reaction we get back. Normal force comes in pairs so if the persons force makes the book in X direction to make contact with wall , the wall gives off a contact force back.

[image]

And I think the misconception of normal force being in Y direction came from gravity
Gravity is not the **cause** for normal force ( as action reaction pair) , It only induces it , the force of gravity's equal and opposite reaction is by the earth coming towards you (negligible) , the gravity only induces this so that when the book or any object gets in contact with surface a normal force acts , keep in mind the force starts slowly (gravity>normal) but with due time(more friction keeps on acting) they equal each other and cancel out

Comment: Thanks a lot Naveen V. That is very comprehensive reply.

Comment: @naveenv I somehow don't agree with your answer..in the first diagram you made, normal force exerted by the ball vertically downwards, which is actually not true, normal force always acts perpendicularly to the surface and for a spherical of curved surfaces, towards the centre or perpendicularly to the tangent passing through the centre of that curve. Read the comment made above by someone to the question.

Comment: @TejasDahake Im very sorry , that was the force of gravity on the ball the normal force is perpendicular to the ball ( from the center of ball to the slide) , I will edit my post thanks for the comment !